# 2011 Macbook Pro internal trackpad unresponsive after cleaning

Tags: mac, macbook, macbook-pro

Alright, didn't think about it while I was doing it, but I cleaned off the body of my mac with a handy wipe like thing since it was getting grimey from my travels. But after cleaning everything off I realized I wiped my trackpad in the process and its acting wonkey for a lack of better description.

My touch is being responded to but only in part, its seems like my trackpad is either struggling to keep up with the movement, or just having a serious brain fart as it seems Ill have a 2 or 3 finger gesture occur while only using a single finger or the other way around.

So I am wondering maybe in the process of wiping I messed up the calibration, and need to reset it. It doesnt appear that any liquid got in (not like there was any accumulated during the wipe down but worth mentioing) I have also restarted and or shut down the mac a few times since, and its still acting up.

I remember a long time ago reading something somewhere about being able to restart the mac, and press a key combo to in a sense wipe any memory issues that may be causing this.

To best decribe the issue is its acting like my wireless trackpad (which is not enabled or in the same state as me currently) when its batteries are running super low. So Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The NVRAM reset keys on OSX are Command-Option-P-R (http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1379). Not sure if that'll help, though, but it's worth a shot. My only advice would be to try rubbing the trackpad with a dry paper towel to make sure there's no residual moisture; that works for me sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

if you are unable to get it to work by trying any other method, i would recommend (only as a last resort) getting your trackpad replaced. (unless you want to just use your wireless trackpad) you could get it done without voiding your warranty at an apple store, or you could buy one online and do it yourself. ive seen them for sale at around $70 for the 13-inch macbooks, and ive also seen several instructional videos on how to do it. the process of replacing it yourself isnt that complicated, as long as you carefully follow instructions and pay attention to what you're doing. if you decide you want to replace it yourself, check out a few videos first to make sure you're comfortable doing it.